# Netflix Challenge - some help with SVD/SoftImpute

Tags: r, cross-validation, model-selection, large-data, svd

I'm currently working on the Netflix Challenge with the original huge dataset and have run into some problems. I don't have access to any servers or computing clusters so I've been running everything (slowly) on my personal machine.

I'm trying to implement the softImpute function in R and the algorithm converges in a reasonable amount of time. However, I can't feasibly do cross validation (SV) to optimize the best "rank.max" and "lambda" values in order to get the result.

I'm wondering if there is some sort of rule of thumb for these collaborative filtering problems in terms of what rank to choose based on the dimensions of your data matrix and perhaps an estimate on what lambda to then select. I understand this will never be as accurate as CV and parameter optimising but perhaps some basic rule of thumb can help me get a closer answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to pick this up so long after you posted. I think it's a really interesting question.

For lambda, the function lambda0 in the softImpute package provides the minimum starting value for a zero solution. Others* have posted that lambda should be about 60% of the rank.max, but I'm not sure what this is based on.

For rank.max, this post* uses the elbow point of the scree plot. This seems a sensible point, though obviously it's subjective.

I don't have any great experience to really back this up, but I mention it in case these had gone under your radar. How did you resolve it in the end?

*http://www.r-bloggers.com/incomplete-data-by-design-bringing-machine-learning-to-marketing-research/